# how to visualize page_source returned from selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver') 
...
browser.find_element_by_id('findOffice').submit()
```

Then `browser.page_source` gives me HTML of the resulting page, which is very messy.

Is there any way I could visualize the resulting page rather than handle the messy html?

My need to fill in some forms and submit to the website, and to see what result the website returns given my request.
Is selenium suitable or powerful for my need?

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't run selenium in headless mode then you can view the browser window while running your script

Comment: The problem I am having is that after I do ```browser.find_element_by_xpath(..).click()```, the bot verification pops out and asks to select all images with horse...  Is this because the website detects the selenium?